# Criar um script para verificar se a tabela possui chave primaria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso criar um script para verificar se uma tabela possui `primary key`, caso não tenha, é adicionado a `primary key`.

Eu encontrei esta forma para fazer o script, nas não entendi onde que ele tira o nome desta tabela `"INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"`, e no `where "CONSTRAINT_TYPE"` e `"TABLE_SCHEMA"`.

Estou começando a aprende a mexer no SQL, se alguém puder sanar minha dúvida agradeço.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Persons' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
END
```

Comment: o script pode até funcionar e vc pode usar como forma didática, mas não existe aplicação real para isso. Chaves primárias não são criadas em segundo momento, em tempo de execução, e sim em tempo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Não sei o que pensar dessa pergunta. Eu até achei interessante a dúvida, como curiosidade técnica, mas me dá um certo frio na barriga imaginar onde seria usado isso na prática.

Comment: Bacco, provavelmente esta tabela é usado só para carregar um drop, que fez tabela não se preocupou em colocar primary key pensando que só iria ser usada na drop, mais o sistema cresce e ouve uma necessidade  em criar  a primary key para vincular com outra tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186778(v=sql.120).aspx) é um schema especial do SQL Server, usado para obter metadados das bases de dados que estão no servidor em questão.

Se você executar:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

Verá que todas as *constraints* de tabelas dos bancos de dados serão exibidas no resultado. O que você está fazendo com este select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Persons' 
and COLUMN_NAME = 'P_Id' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo'
```

É pesquisar no schema `dbo`, tabela `Persons` e coluna `P_Id` se existe uma chave primária associada a ela. Se não existe, executa este comando:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Krispim,

utilize o seguinte select:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Persons' and COLUMN_NAME = 'P_Id' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
END
```

O comando "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" consegue ter a informação de todos os metadados da atual base de dados, ele é utilizando juntamente com outro comando (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES [link fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186778(v=sql.120).aspx))

No caso utilizando o comando "KEY_COLUMN_USAGE"(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE) será listado todos os campos que são chave primaria e em qual tabelas estão.

Fazendo o select que sugeri você consegue descobrir se a tabela "Persons" possui a chave no campo "P_Id", se não retornar nada no select é que ela não está com a chave primária então o alter table será executado, se encontrar nada será feito.

Espero ter ajudado e esclarecido algumas dúvidas dos comandos.